# Excel - Sum of values in a column given the order type available in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have excel 2010 and I am trying to do the following (the table below has been done manually)

```
Customer       Order type        Revenue         Sum
001            Pears             50              
001            Plums             70        
001            Strawberries      10              130
002            Pears             10
002            Strawberries      20              30
003            Pears             30
003            Plums             10
003            Strawberries      10              50
```

Basically I have data from the first 3 columns and I want to have an aggregate value in the fourth column for every customer: that is sum all the revenue from customer xxx

This should have been done by the BI too, I use, however I have not enough privileges to work this out with the appropriate sql queries

I have to do this for thousands of records, any idea about which function can make it? This is an interesting topic for anyone dealing with revenue reports.

Thanks

RESOLUTION: I tried the formula suggested by Santosh, it works pretty well. You get the sum only once, then you just do some basic manipulations and you can get one row woth the total revenue per customer which is what I was looking for.

Thank you!

Comment: Either Pivot table or SUMIF() can do this

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `SUMIF` function. `=IF(A2=A3,"",SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C))` drag it.

[image]

Comment: I tested this formula; it gives the right answer, but it displays it on every row.

Comment: @JamesJenkins have updated it.

Comment: That works better :)

Comment: + 1 Another good one

Comment: @Santosh tried your formula, works pretty well, it actually displays the sum once, then with some copy&paste manipulations I obtained the results I wanted

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula in D2 filled down

`=IF(A3=A2,"",SUM(C$2:C2)-SUM(D$1:D1))`

see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/533xrsyach4k0ry/Customer_sum.xls)

Comment: I tested this formula; It gives very wrong answers. -40, -150, & -200 but it does only display it at the end of the customer number.

Comment: + 1 Barry and wrong formula?... That would be a first :)

Comment: Thanks Sid! - I tested the formula and it works assuming the data is laid out as per Santosh's picture - I'm trying to attach a sample but having problems at the moment.........

Comment: I added a link to a sample file containing the suggested formula, it seems to return the required values......

Comment: I pasted it twice, I must have killed it somehow. Ah ha, I see the problem, I pasted it into column F, and it is dependent on being in column D. Sorry my error

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with two formulas, where one column is hidden.

In D2, running sum of the values

```
=IF(A2=A1,C2+D1,C2)
```

In E2, display on the last values

```
=IF(A2=A3,"",D2)
```

Hide column D, so the running sum is not displayed

[image: Sum]

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [pivot table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-report-HP010089893.aspx).  This will give you a unique list of customers and sum up the values in the Revenue field.

Answer (score 0):

Use of Subtotal would seem easiest.